# How to delete uploaded files automatically after 2 days

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, server, timer

I have a chat application where users send files to each other. Each file must be deleted after 2 days.

For this purpose, I recursively check all the files every 4 hours and delete those that have been created for more than 2 days.

But this work consumes a lot of my server's CPU, which disrupts the application's work. Because the number of files to be checked is very large and the size of all of them is about 10 GB.

Now, if as soon as each file is uploaded, a timer is activated to delete that file after 2 days, is this better? Considering that a file is uploaded almost every second and the number of timers may be very high.

My recursive solution:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const rootDir = require('../config').rootDir
const log = require('../da/log');

const DIRECTORY_MESSAGES = rootDir + '/file/messages';
const DIRECTORY_AVATARS = rootDir + '/file/avatars';
const INTERVAL_MINUTES_MESSAGES = 240;
const INTERVAL_MINUTES_AVATARS = 265;
const ACCESS_DAYS_MESSAGES = 2;
const ACCESS_DAYS_AVATARS = 10;
/*
* Remove files that access times is older than {fileAccessHours}.
* Runs every {removeEveryMinutes}
* */
module.exports = {
    start: function () {
        setInterval(deleteFiles.bind(this, DIRECTORY_MESSAGES, ACCESS_DAYS_MESSAGES), INTERVAL_MINUTES_MESSAGES * 60_000)
        setInterval(deleteFiles.bind(this, DIRECTORY_AVATARS, ACCESS_DAYS_AVATARS), INTERVAL_MINUTES_AVATARS * 60_000)
    }
}

function deleteFiles(dir, accessDays) {
    walkDir(dir, function (path, isDirectory) {
        try {
            if (isDirectory) {
                if (path === dir) {
                    return;
                }
                return fs.rmdir(path, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        return log.error(__filename + ' :deleteFiles, fs.rmdir, ' + err);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                fs.stat(path, function (err, stat) {
                    try {

                        const now = new Date().getTime();
                        const endTime = new Date(stat.atime).getTime() + accessDays * 86_400_000;
                        if (err) {
                            return log.error(__filename + ' :deleteFiles, fs.stat, ' + err);
                        }
                        if (now > endTime) {
                            return fs.unlink(path, function (err) {
                                if (err) {
                                    return log.error(__filename + ' :deleteFiles, fs.unlink, ' + err);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log('File Deleter: walkDir: callback: fs.stat: ' + err);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('File Deleter: walkDir: callback' + err);
        }
    });
}

function walkDir(dir, callback) {
    try {
        let files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
        if (files.length === 0) {
            callback(dir, /* isDirectory */ true);
        } else {
            files.forEach(f => {
                let dirPath = path.join(dir, f);
                let isDirectory = fs.statSync(dirPath).isDirectory();
                isDirectory ? walkDir(dirPath, callback) : callback(path.join(dir, f), /* isDirectory */ false);
            });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('File Deleter: walkDir: ' + err);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the best approach could be to add a separate cron job or some other job that runs at regular intervals and perform the cleaning logic, ideally we should not add this kind of logic in application code if it is going to affect CPU/Memory, better to create a separate job may be cron job that runs at regular intervals and do the clean up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the directory walk but don't reinvent the wheel.  eg using gnu find:

```
 find /path/to/directory -type f -ctime +2 -delete
```

run that from cron.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, if as soon as each file is uploaded, a timer is activated to delete that file after 2 days, is this better?

"Better" is a slippery concept, but consider what happens if your server crashes and restarts, or you have to shut it down to upgrade, etc.: Those timers are lost, and you have to do the directory-walking thing again.

This seems like an application for a simple database. It can be an in-process DB backed by a file (such as an `sqlite` DB) or these days it's pretty simple to get a proper DB process going as well. You record the date/time and path of the files when uploaded, then periodically query the DB to see what exact files have expired and need deleting. No directory walking required. If using a separate DB (rather than in-process), the cleanup could even be a separate process as [A R K suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77501584/how-to-delete-uploaded-files-automatically-after-2-days/77501620#comment136631004_77501584) rather than tying up the server's main Node.js thread.

Answer (score 0):

*(Design perspective)*

I would create a queue of "Expiration" objects + a "Deleter" worker-thread that empties it:

```cpp
struct Expiration
{
    Time expiration_date_and_time; // On construction set Now() + 48h
    String full_path;
}
```

1. On every file that is uploaded, add an object to the **Back** of the queue and store the queue in a file for persistence (crash / restart scenario). If the queue was empty, *Awake* the "Deleter" worker-thread after the addition.
2. The "Deleter" worker-thread deletes the **Front** of the queue repeatedly until the **Front** is not yet expired (in case that more than one file uploaded at the same time) and update the persistence file. After, it enters to *Sleep* until the time to delete the Front of the queue.
3. On Start: The "Deleter" worker-thread loads the queue from the persistence file and goes to step 2.

--

- Ensure the queue's access is safeguarded with a mutex, as it serves as a shared resource for both the file-adding thread and the deleter worker-thread responsible for file removal.